# How to extract the middle digit from the image url

Tags: php

How to trim the front 6 numbers and last string and extension of the below url and display the 1337 ,(1337 is the id of the image.)

```
1330001337_jenir.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = substr(strstr($name, '_', true), 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try regex:

```
preg_match("/(?:\d){6}(\d+)/", "1330001337_jenir.jpg", $matches);

echo $matches[2];
```

Comment: This could be improved as `/(?:\d){6}(\d+)/`. This way, the first 6 digits aren't returned as matches and then the next group is the entire group of numbers - no need to check for an underscore or any other characters.

Comment: @newfurniturey: Thanks. I have to stop using those non-greedy capturing groups so much...

Answer (score 0):

Use [substr](http://php.net/substr) + [explode](http://php.net/explode) to get your number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code chunk --

```
$mystr = "1330001337_jenir.jpg";

echo substr($mystr,6,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
<?php
 $myStr='1330001337_jenir.jpg';

 $strArray=explode($myStr,'-');
 $numStr=substr($strArray[0],6); //returns 1337

 $nameStr=substr($strArray[1],0,-4);  //returns jenir

 ?>
```